# Which side of a join should I select from if both sides have the same information?

Tags: mysql, join

In the example here:

```
Left Join Table1 on Table2.Number = Table1.Number
```

If table 1 has 1,000,000 instances of number '1', and Table 2 has just 1 instance of the number '1', would it affect performance if I did:

```
Select Table1.Number from Table2 Left Join Table1 on Table2.Number = Table1.Number
```

Vs

```
Select Table2.Number from Table2 left join Table1 on Table2.Number = Table1.Number
```

Or would they both come out at the same speed?

Comment: It's not clear why would you want to use _outer_ join in this case. For inner join, it's the optimizer's task to choose the better way of joining the tables, so it'll probably make no difference.

Comment: From my opinion 2nd will be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both these values should already be in memory, as they are both needed to evaluate the `join` condition. It does not matter which one you have in your select list.